# How does css apply its style properties

Tags: css, styles

Shouldn't the css style be changed permanently once it gets applied?
see below:

```
 <style>
div{width:100px;height:100px;background-color:red}
div:hover{background-color:black}
</style>

<body>
<div></div>
</body>
```

I mean to say that when `hover` occurs on the element the background color of the element gets changed, and once changed it should be changed permanently because the hover state has changed the property of the element.

i also have seen the cases which have permanently changed the property

Comment: No, that's not how it works.

Comment: `:hover` only applies while the mouse is over the element.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pseudo-class-selectors#dynamic-pseudo-classes

Comment: In addition, the effect of hovering over something to make a permanent change is almost never seen on the web.

Comment: @Richard, though that link is fine for this particular situation, you should try to avoid linking to old specs!

Comment: @jmeas - It's [W3C Recommendation 07 June 2011](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cover.html). Doesn't seem very old to me. ?

Comment: I suppose the [Selectors Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#the-user-action-pseudo-classes-hover-act) recommendation is a little newer - Sept 2011.

Comment: @Richard JP Le Guen i also have seen the case  which have permanently changed the property

Comment: @Richard Dates are irrelevant; it's whether or not something has been released since then or not. In this case, [there has been something released.](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/).

Comment: @MaizerePathak The site you've seen has changed the property permanently with JavaScript. You can't do it in CSS alone.

Comment: @Juhana should i show u the example but its quite long code and it is being done in css3 animation.when the user hovers the element animation runs changing all the properties defined for the element permanently.

Comment: Yeah, ok, but that has nothing to do with `:hover`, has it?

Comment: Love the debate. No body seems to be bothered that the OP is confused with how the :hover works.

Answer (score 2):

No, `hover` means that this style is being applied only when the mouse hovers over the element. As soon as the mouse stops hovering over the element, the style reverts back to what it was before.

If you're looking to make permanent changes like this, you're likely going to need JavaScript.

Comment: i have seen some cases tht have changed the css property permanently

Comment: Yup, through JavaScript I'd imagine.

Comment: it has done only through css3

Comment: should i show u the example but its quite long code and it is being done in css3 animation.when the user hovers the element animation runs changing all the properties defined for the element permanently

Answer (score 0):

ezuk's answer is great (accept that one), but I was bored and thought of a very silly solution using just CSS.

### HTML

```
<div>
  <span>hello</span>
</div>​
```

### CSS

```
body, html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
div {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #eee;
}
div:hover {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
div:hover > span {
  background-color: #555;
}
```

[View on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bkaf8/)

It works until you mouse out of the browser (or iFrame or whatever)

:)